# Add custom code snippets with AUCTeX

Tags: auctex

I have started using Emacs a couple weeks ago and so far I got it to do pretty much everything I wanted. Recently, I started using Emacs and AUCTeX to write a GUI specification document. For each GUI element I have a corresponding LaTeX snippet that I can insert in the specification to start from, like this, for example:

```tex
\item \texttt{Button}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Label]    Here I add a description for the wanted button label...
        \item[Readonly] etc...
        \item[Enabled]
        \item[Visible]
        \item[Tooltip]
        \item[Alternate control]
        \item[Events]
        \item[Misc]
    \end{description}
```

To include it in the specification, I cut and paste it from another document. Copying and pasting works, but is tedious. What I would like to achieve with Emacs and AUCTeX is to type, from within Emacs, something like `M-x button` so that it adds the corresponding code snippet directly from the current cursor position. I'd like this snippet to be available only when a `.tex` file is opened.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `YASnippet` Emacs package. `M-x package-install RET yasnippet`. Might find this useful or just Google for examples: [tutorial](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html)
Once installed and you have `(yas-global-mode t)` in your .emacs file, it will show a menu bar YASnippet.

Once YASnippet is installed try this. Save the following in a file ~/.emacs.d/snippets/latex-mode/test.yasnippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: test
# key: test_
# --
\item \texttt{Button}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Label]     ${1:Add description}
        \item[Readonly] etc...
        \item[Enabled]
        \item[Visible]
        \item[Tooltip]
        \item[Alternate control]
        \item[Events]
        \item[Misc]
    \end{description}$0
```

Then when you type "test_" TAB it should insert your code at point. Once you type in your description press TAB it will take you to the end of your code. The $1, $2, etc is the location of the cursor after each TAB, $0 is last TAB.

Comment: The tutorial looks promising!

Comment: This works very well.